# Transfer messages of different topics to hdfs by kafka-connect-hdfs

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to transfer data from kafka to hdfs by confluent, and I do the experiments by the [quickstart](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart.html#quickstart) in CLI model successfully.

Now, I intend to deploy confluent platform on production environment, Is there any tutorial about distributed deployment in detail?

And if there are many topics in kafka, such as register_info, video_play_info, video_like_info, video_repost_info and etc.

I need to process messages by different converters, and transfer to different hive table.

what should i?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt  THX

Answer (score 0):

> I need to process messages by different converters, and transfer to different hive table

1. Run `bin/connect-distributed etc/kafka/connect-distributed.propeties`
2. Create individual JSON files for each HDFS Connector
3. POST them to the REST endpoint of Kafka Connect

[Distributed mode is documented here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#distributed-mode)